# Is there an expression for cutting ties or calling off something that is ultimately unfavorable to both parties?

Tags: phrases, expressions, figures-of-speech

In particular, ending something that one of the parties is still attached to. For instance, in a relationship, if one person doesn't want to go through the short term struggle of a breakup (and is therefore unwilling to take action), but the two both know they are better off separated for long term happiness. The other person has more sense and calls it off.

Apologies for being rambly and for any grammar mistakes.

Comment: you can call it "acting mature" i guess !!

Comment: ...or maybe "a divorce of convenience."

Comment: No, a divorce of convenience is willingly obtained by both parties to take advantage of laws that benefit them both as single parties.

Comment: @TechieBee Or even *maturely*, or *with maturity*.

Comment: @Marcus Busby "amicable (or 'out of court') settlement?"

Answer (score 1):

You can say she:

- broke the cycle of misery
- broke the cycle of unhappiness
- broke the cycle of pain
- broke the cycle of abuse
- broke the cycle of violence
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions sorted by descending order of preference:

***[1. Take a turn for the better](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+turn+for+the+better)***

> to start to improve; to start to get well.

**Usage:** It was not smooth but I broke up with Kathy and *took a turn for the better*.

***[2. for good](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+good)***

> forever; permanently

**Usage:** Man, I finally broke up with Kathy *for good*.

***[3. Good riddance](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+riddance)***

> Used to express relief that someone or something has been gotten rid of.

**Usage:** I'm happy that I took the bold step and broke up with Kathy. *Good riddance*!

Note that #3 can be used only if Kathy was bothering you, causing a lot of troubles in the relationship.

All idiom references : Dictionary.com